# Bootstrap Datetimepicker - blur() when pressing enter

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

While editing **directly** the date inside the `input`-field of my datetimepicker (without opening the widget), I want by keypressing enter to confirm the entered date.

I think that just calling `blur()` should that do.

But I don't know how to run `blur()`on the `input`-field of my datetimepicker. Has anybody an idea?

```
$(".mydatepicker").datetimepicker({
    locale: "de",
    format: "L",
    minDate: "1900/01/01",
    keyBinds: {
        enter: function () {
            // "this.input.blur();"
        }
    }
})
```

Not the cleanest, but working **Solution**:

```
$(".mydatepicker").datetimepicker({
    locale: "de",
    format: "L",
    minDate: "1900/01/01",
    keyBinds: {
        enter: function () {
            this.show();
            this.hide();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You could programmatically `hide()` and `show()` the picker when you want it using `dp.hide()` or `dp.show()`. Check the [Docs](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dphide)

Comment: I would rather use ok and cancel button to confirm the selected date or use submit button to confirm.

Comment: @Justcode with "confirming" i meant that focus of the `input`-element would disappear and the widget would take my manually editted date when opening it.

Comment: @MartijnVissers `this.show();
                        this.hide();` actually works. well, not the cleanest solution, but it works. thank you!

Comment: No problem, I will add it as an answer to your question for you to accept and for others to find more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added as answer because OP liked the solution.

Rather than using `blur()` another option is to use `dp.hide()` and `dp.show()` when the picker needs to be open or closed. With this there is more control and it may be easier since focus and blur programming *can* be a bit annoying

Check the [docs](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dphide) for more information